# Transform not working in pose mode

Tags: transforms, pose-mode

I'm fairly new to this.
I have a rig set up, and there's one bone that will not transform in pose mode. If I try to move it/rotate it using the 3D manipulator widget, it does that free rotate thing with the black arrow instead. However, it does work properly in Edit Mode. Manipulate center points is disabled.

### EDIT: Screenshots.

[image: description]

Comment: could you please post either a screenshot, or provide the blend file at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I parented the bone that wouldn't move with the one below it and changed it to Keep Offset, and now I am able to move it.

Comment: if bones are parented in edit mode using the 'connected' option, child bones cannot be translated away from their parents any more (that's the purpose of connecting them). What you did was exactly what's needed. You can also use Alt+P -> Disconnect Bone to break the connection but keep the hierachy.